# flutter search in multiple strings

Tags: flutter

I have search field that filter my list and it works fine I just want to make small changes to it:

**Logic**

1. Back to full list when user clear search field
2. search also be included of `ListTile->subtitle` currently only search in `title`

**Code** `search function is commented for better understanding`

```
List<World> locations = [...]


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
            children: [
                buildSearch(),
                Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: locations.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Card(
                                child: ListTile(
                                    onTap: () {},
                                    title: Text(locations[index].location),
                                    subtitle: Text(locations[index].country),
                                ),
                            ),
                        },
                    ),
                ),
            ],
        ),
    ),
}

Widget buildSearch() => SearchWidget(
    text: query,
    hintText: 'Search for location',
    onChanged: searchLocation,
);

void searchLocation(String query) async {
    // currently only search in titles (need to add subtitle as well)
    final newLocations = locations.where((location) {
        final nameLower = location.location.toLowerCase();
        final searchLower = query.toLowerCase();
        return nameLower.contains(searchLower);
    }).toList();

    // when user clear search or remove letters list wont back to it's default
    setState(() {
        this.query = query;
        this.locations = newLocations;
    });
}
```

**Any suggestions?**

## Update

here is my `SearchWidget` file (just in case)

```
class SearchWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  final ValueChanged<String> onChanged;
  final String hintText;

  const SearchWidget({
    Key key,
    this.text,
    this.onChanged,
    this.hintText,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SearchWidgetState createState() => _SearchWidgetState();
}

class _SearchWidgetState extends State<SearchWidget> {
  final controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final styleActive = TextStyle(color: Colors.black);
    final styleHint = TextStyle(color: Colors.black54);
    final style = widget.text.isEmpty ? styleHint : styleActive;

    return Container(
      height: 42,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 16, 16),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        color: Colors.white,
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black26),
      ),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
      child: TextField(
        controller: controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          icon: Icon(Icons.search, color: style.color),
          suffixIcon: widget.text.isNotEmpty
              ? GestureDetector(
            child: Icon(Icons.close, color: style.color),
            onTap: () {
              controller.clear();
              widget.onChanged('');
              FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
            },
          )
              : null,
          hintText: widget.hintText,
          hintStyle: style,
          border: InputBorder.none,
        ),
        style: style,
        onChanged: widget.onChanged,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## UPDATE 2

I've managed to fix #2 in my logic and get subtitles include search results by following code (clear search issue still remains)

```
void searchLocation(String query) async {
    final newLocations = locations.where((location) {
      final nameLower = location.location.toLowerCase();
      final countryLower = location.country.toLowerCase(); // added
      final searchLower = query.toLowerCase();
      return nameLower.contains(searchLower) || countryLower.contains(searchLower); //changed
    }).toList();

    setState(() {
      this.query = query;
      this.locations = newLocations;
    });
  }
```

**Note:**

I've accepted `Yair Chen` answer but I need to make some clarifications to address the issue:

Based on `Yair Chen` answer I had to create new list `List<World> filteredLocations = [];`

Then in my `ListView.builder` I've changed `itemCount` and `child` like following:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: filteredLocations.isNotEmpty ? filteredLocations.length : locations.length,
  //...
  child: filteredLocations.isNotEmpty ? card(... //filteredLocations[index].location//...) : Card(... //locations[index].location// ...),
```

This way index issue on filtered result solved and card data will get data regarding of the list they are returning from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another list called filteredLocations and then save to the filtered location the new list. The function .where() changes the original List as well which you dont want. You can shallow copy (using spread operator) the list and then create a new list that matches the query like that:

```
void searchLocation(String query) async {
    // currently only search in titles (need to add subtitle as well)
    // [...locations] copies the list to not change original list
    final newLocations = [...locations].where((location) {
        final nameLower = location.location.toLowerCase();
        final searchLower = query.toLowerCase();

        // Also adding subtitle check (whether the name contains it or the subtitle does
        return nameLower.contains(searchLower) || location.subtitle.toLowerCase().contains(searchLower);
    }).toList();

    // when user clear search or remove letters list wont back to it's default
    setState(() {
        this.query = query;
        this.filteredLocations = newLocations;
    });
}
```

This way the original list will never be changed and only the filteredList will be updated. It'll also fix the issue that when the string is empty you want all the items to appear.

Good luck and let me know if you need anything else :)

Comment: Hi, so you mean I make a list like this `List<World> filteredLocations = [];` and then how do I get this list items in my view? as you can see in my `ListView.builder(` I am using `locations` list.

Comment: So in the ListView.builder use the filteredLocations and then you'll only see the locations that answer the query. Every time you use setState in the search function it'll render again with the correct locations.

Comment: :| either I don't get your point or you're off topic! if I use `filteredLocations` in `ListView.builder` in first load then my list will be empty when user opens the page as there is no query in first load. (maybe you can update your answer?)

Comment: I've found the solution.

Comment: Thank you, I also added `note` part to my question in order to complete your answer

Comment: Great! You can also assign the locations list values to the filteredLocations at initState and then everything will work without extra conditions because from then the locations will just be filtered.

Comment: Feel free to update your answer it might help bigger audience in future. (because i have no idea about what you just said :D)